# Nuxt static generate doesn't set cookies in production mode

Tags: javascript, cookies, nuxt.js

i'm using [cookie-universal-nuxt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-universal-nuxt) plugin to set cookies in nuxt js. it is works fine in development, but in production doesn't save or set cookies.

i build my project with `npm run generate` command.

for example this is my `cookiePolicy` component:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      cookieConsent: false
    }
  },
  created() {
    const cookie = this.$cookies.get('cookie-consent')
    if (cookie) {
      if (cookie === 'true')
        this.cookieConsent = Boolean(this.$cookies.get('cookie-consent'))
    } else {
      this.setCookie()
    }
  },
  methods: {
    accept() {
      this.cookieConsent = !this.cookieConsent
      this.setCookie()
    },
    setCookie() {
      this.$cookies.set('cookie-consent', this.cookieConsent, {
        maxAge: 365 * 24 * 60 * 60
      })
    }
  }
}
```

i uploaded my project to host, and in developer tools cookies are set.
but actually it has problem.

i run `npm run build` and `npm run start` and run project in production mode in my computer and everything works fine.

Comment: try to do this cookie setting/getting process in the mounted method.

Comment: @HardikShah but it still has a problem, on first website loading, it display the cookiePolicy component, when loading finished, cookiePolicy disappeared.

Comment: fixed with <client-only>

Comment: this thing you can do inside asyncData also na.. if you are doing inside pages.
as you are using cookie-universal-nuxt which will be accessible in async Data via app.$cookies.get